# Bot Framework .Net, How I can get either the Username, Id, Token from my Web App to Bot

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I created a Bot that will interact with the currently logged-in user from my Web(React-app). So in my Website if I am currently login and if I click the bot which I embedded using Web Chat. So I want to get that token/username/id which I saved in the cookies/state. How can I pass that data to the Bot? So that my Bot will know who he's talking to. Because I don't want my Bot to login again since he is already logged-in in my Web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find some resources and it worked on my end. 

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

- (Another example) https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42096464/82071374-a1fc8680-969b-11ea-8080-23c618163096.png